# QGLBuffer::map returns NULL?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm trying to use [QGLbuffer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/qglbuffer.html) to display an image.
Sequence is something like:

```
initializeGL() {
  glbuffer= QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::PixelUnpackBuffer);        
  glbuffer.create();
  glbuffer.bind();
  glbuffer.allocate(image_width*image_height*4); // RGBA
  glbuffer.release();
}

// Attempting to write an image directly the graphics memory.
// map() should map the texture into the address space and give me an address in the   
// to write directly to  but always returns NULL
unsigned char* dest = glbuffer.map(QGLBuffer::WriteOnly);  FAILS
MyGetImageFunction( dest );         
glbuffer.unmap();

paint() {
  glbuffer.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0,0); glVertex2i(0,height());
    glTexCoord2i(0,1); glVertex2i(0,0);
    glTexCoord2i(1,1); glVertex2i(width(),0);
    glTexCoord2i(1,0); glVertex2i(width(),height());
    glEnd();             
  glbuffer.release();
}
```

There aren't any examples of using GLBuffer in this way, it's pretty new

Edit --- for search here is the working solution -------

```
 // Where glbuffer is defined as  
 glbuffer= QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::PixelUnpackBuffer); 

// sequence to get a pointer into a PBO, write data to it and copy it to a texture
glbuffer.bind(); // bind before doing anything
unsigned char *dest = (unsigned char*)glbuffer.map(QGLBuffer::WriteOnly);
MyGetImageFunction(dest);                           
glbuffer.unmap(); // need to unbind before the rest of openGL can access the PBO

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);                       
// Note 'NULL' because memory is now onboard the card                                                                                   
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0,0, image_width, image_height, glFormatExt, glType, NULL);  
glbuffer.release();  // but don't release until finished the copy


// PaintGL function
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0,0); glVertex2i(0,height());
    glTexCoord2i(0,1); glVertex2i(0,0);
    glTexCoord2i(1,1); glVertex2i(width(),0);
    glTexCoord2i(1,0); glVertex2i(width(),height());
glEnd();
```

Comment: Maybe I don't follow, but why the release() before map()?

Comment: @VJovic - why .map() always returns NULL

Comment: @Bart - docs suggest that each bind is matched with a release

Comment: @VJovic - yes it's a mid range NVidia card. The raw textures version works but i was trying to optomise the number of data copies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should bind the buffer before mapping it!**

In the [documentation for QGLBuffer::map](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qglbuffer.html#map):

> It is assumed that create() has been called on this buffer and **that it has been bound to the current context**.

In addition to VJovic's comments, I think you are missing a few points about PBOs:

A pixel unpack buffer does not give you a pointer to the graphics texture. It is a separate piece of memory allocated on the graphics card to which you can write to directly from the CPU.

The buffer can be copied into a texture by a glTexSubImage2D(....., 0) call, with the texture being bound as well, which you do not do. (0 is the offset into the pixel buffer). The copy is needed partly because textures have a different layout than linear pixel buffers.

See [this page](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html) for a good explanation of PBO usages (I used it a few weeks ago to do async texture upload).

Comment: Got it - is simply a wrapper around glMapBufferARB()? So the data is written directly to the card but NOT to a texture. But the update from  PBO to texture is on the GPU so fast ?  Otherwise I coudln't see the point in a PBO

Comment: @MartinBeckett Well, yes. It's probably much faster to copy from PBO to texture than from CPU to texture, but I don't know if copying from CPU to PBO to texture is at a whole faster than CPU->texture. But keep in mind that the point of PBOs is not only the possible GPU storage, but also the asynchronity of the update. With a PBO bound, glTexImage2D returns immediately and the data can be copied from PBO to texture while doing other things on the CPU. Look at Macke's link for streaming texture upload as the perfect example. And of course, they are also useful for render-to-VBO and such things.

Comment: @Christian, I currently use textures and get about 50% max bus speed into the card. Ultimate aim is write to a PBO then CUDA to transform to a texture. Not sure async helps me here - the system bus is going to be so full of data uploading to the GPU I can't do anything else anyway!

Comment: @macke - thanks, I read that as it had to be in the thread with the current context. I forgot the bind/release.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: You can use several threads to stream data into PBOs to the GPU, since once you've mapped the buffers there's no requirement that the buffer accesses happens from the thread with the context. (It's just memory addressess anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

[create](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/qglbuffer.html#create) will return false if the GL implementation does not support buffers, or there is no current QGLContext.

[bind](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/qglbuffer.html#bind) returns false if binding was not possible, usually because type() is not supported on this GL implementation.

You are not checking if these two functions passed.

Comment: bind() and create() return true, I just wanted to simplify the code here. allocate doesn't have a return value but size() returns the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same thing, map returns `NULL`. When I used the following order it is solved.

```
bool success = mPixelBuffer->create();
mPixelBuffer->setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::DynamicDraw);
success = mPixelBuffer->bind();
mPixelBuffer->allocate(sizeof(imageData));
void* ptr =mPixelBuffer->map(QGLBuffer::ReadOnly);
```